# Remove php extention with Godaddy hosting

Tags: php, .htaccess, shared-hosting

I am trying to hide the php file extensions. I am using godaddy hosting and I have been told I may need to do something additional. Currently I have the below code and it does not want to work.

I receive the following error:

Not Found

The requested URL /domain.ca/products/ was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

My link is going to http://www.domain.ca/products/

```
Options +MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using below code for php extention

```
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
    RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: There's no need for the QSA flag, because you don't modify the query string.